Using @kolkov/angular-editor alignment not in the html
I am using in my angular @kolkov/angular-editor. However, when displaying the htmlContent, it does not show the alignments.
However, when I press on the html button (in the upper right) corner. It displays it correctly.
How could I get the html from that button.
Thank you,
this us the button and result:

and this is the html result:

